# 404 on Nextjs API routes

Tags: typescript, next.js, http-status-code-404

I can't call my route API (404) in my new nextjs project.

My route API is in src/app/api/speed.js

In my page src/app/page.tsx, I do:

```
fetch("api/speed").then(res=>res.json).then(data=>alert(data.message))
```

But in the network devtools tab, I always get a 404 on GET http://localhost:3000/api/speed

src/app/api/speed.js:

```
export default function handler (_req,res) {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "hey" })
}
```

src/app/page.tsx

```
'use clients;
export default function Home() {
  function handleClick() {
    fetch("api/speed").then(res=>res.json.then(({message})=>alert(message))
  }
 
  return (
    <><main><div onClick={handleClick}>HEY</div></main><>
  )
}
```

**Note** that it works if I move the API route to: src/app/api/speed/route.js but the documentation clearly gives the example of: pages/api/hello.js, so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

**Note 2**: I also had to modify the code if the API. The official doc gives a non-working example (deprecated probably). New code:

```
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";
export async function GET(req) {
  return NextResponse.json({message: "hey"})
}
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an API router in the app router, you have to create a file named `route.js/ts` and export the handler functions with the name of the method. like so:

###### src/app/api/speed/route.js

```js
export const GET = () => {
    return Response.json({ data: "hello world" })
}
```

now you can fetch data how you've already done!

```js
fetch("api/speed")
    .then(res=> res.json())
    .then(({ data }) => console.log(data))
```

for more information, you can read the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's the solution I finally implemented (see my Notes) but I tried to use API routes : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes

Comment: @Pleymor you need to have Typescript `5.2` to be able to use the native `Response` class. as per documentation: `TypeScript Warning: Response.json() is only valid from TypeScript 5.2. If you use a lower TypeScript version, you can use NextResponse.json() for typed responses instead.`